# PhoneGap/Cordova preloader

Tags: javascript, cordova, download, preloading

Here is what

- Phonegap Loads index.html and displays splash screen
- Checks web server for a version file that that lists all required external files.
- download all external files that need updating to the application's directory or somewhere on the device that the application has control over preferably not the downloads folder.
- Add script/link tags in the index.html file to include the local files instead of externally loading them.

Currently I have a script that calls a json file on a server that contains an array of links and an array of scripts.

```
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.type = "text/javascript";
script.src = url;
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);
```

This works great however it means each time the app starts that it needs to load all of these external files. minifed is still a few kp as i'm loading angular, jquery, highcharts, my own code, etc...

If I could download them and then link to them locally I can keep an effective diff/version system and only update the files that need to be updated. All others would would already be stored in local and I would just append the local script urls.

Yes I am aware that this may cause issues with iOS app store policies but lets tackle this from a programming perspective before trying to deal with what apple wants to allow.

Answer (score 0):

An idea could be like the following, but may take a lot of work.

You can write a service plugin in android. You can check for updated version at any particular time of the day and download your updated code in background. This way your app can update it's file regularly. Can't tell what's the system name for ios to run program as background service.

Comment: That would only work if updates were always released at the same time otherwise the backend could be out of sync with the frontend. I feel like there should be a way to do this without extra plugins and running at the start-up of the app. Kinda the same way Hydra "Hydration" works.